# Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) 2.0 mystery error

Tags: c#, dynamic, wia

I am viewing code that I have found from [here](http://miljenkobarbir.com/using-a-scanner-without-dialogs-in-net/). When I open the downloaded source code project in vs12, everything works fine. But when I copy the class into my own project there is an error (red squiggly line) under

`WIA.ImageFile image = (WIA.ImageFile)wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, wiaFormatBMP, false);`

All references have been added as far as I can tell. The error description is: "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?"

Any Idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I see. I'll refrain from thanking next time I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have copy/pasted the code, make sure target `.Net Framework` for that project is `4.0 or above (4.5)`.

**EDIT**

You get this error when attempting to compile a solution that uses dynamic types in .NET.
It’s highly unlikely your project is missing a reference to `System.Core.dll` if you are using Visual Studio. Usually this occurs when the project does not have a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`. Add this reference to the references folder and recompile.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it is set to the same .net as the source project.